# Powershell, find users that were disabled in the past 14 days only

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory, windows-scripting

I have a powershell script that his output is showing me everything that was disabled for the past 14 days.
What i'm looking is to change that this script will run from a specific OU and not the whole DC.
I want him to show me only the disabled users for the past 14 days from a specific OU.

The script:

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)

$disabledUsers = Get-ADObject -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "User" -and whenChanged -ge $sixMonthsAgo -and UserAccountControl -band 2'

$server = Get-ADDomainController

foreach ($disabledUser in $disabledUsers)
{
    Get-ADReplicationAttributeMetadata $disabledUser -Server $server -Properties UserAccountControl |
    Where-Object { $_.AttributeName -eq 'UserAccountControl' } | Select Object, LastOriginatingChangeTime |
    Where-Object { $_.LastOriginatingChangeTime -gt $date }
}
```

Comment: [1] change your `-Filter` to put the double quotes ON THE OUTSIDE of the filter string. otherwise your `$Vars` will be treated as literal strings instead of the values in them. ///// [2] you don't set `$sixMonthsAgo`.

Comment: Ditto, and also, why use `Get-ADObject` where you want users? (use `Get-ADUser` instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Filter will make it run quickly
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
get-aduser -filter {Enabled -eq $false -and Modified -ge $date } -Properties Modified | select samaccountname,Modified

Comment: Awesome, that's basically what i needed.
Now i tried to add this "Modified, @{n='Manager';e={(Get-ADUser $_.manager).name}}" in the end so i could see each user manager name , but i see an empty row on the Manager section.
Any idea why?
My final goal for a second script is to get all the users that has been disabled today and send an email to their managers with a message that user "X" that is in their team has been disabled.

Comment: yeah make sure you add manager to the properties 
 $date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
get-aduser -filter {Enabled -eq $false -and Modified -ge $date } -Properties Modified,manager | select samaccountname,Modified,manager

Comment: Yep awesome works "select samaccountname,Modified,@{n='Manager';e={(Get-ADUser $_.manager).name}}"
Now do you have an idea how do i add the sending email for each manager about their users that is disabled?

Comment: you will need to use a foreach loop to loop through all the managers since you are calling the get-aduser call it again for email address @{n='ManagerEmail';e={(Get-ADUser $_.manager -properties mail ).mail}}"

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware that your current script actually works only if an object has not been modified since it was disabled.
But as far as I know, it is the only way without logging specificly userAccountControl attribute modification (and this cannot still log 100% of cases since once disabled, an object can see his userAccountControl modified without enabling it).

Based on "user is never modified after he was disabled" :

```
Search-ADAccount -SearchBase "OU=myOU,DC=mydom,DC=adds" -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly | Get-ADUser -Properties whenChanged | Where whenChanged -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
```

Comment: Nice, although I would compare the whenChanged date to `(Get-Date).AddDays(-14).Date`, to not have it depend on the actual time of day at which the script runs. +1